# How to manually create a cron job to run a Django script?

Tags: python, django, cron

I have been trying to run some code as a cron job using Django. There are a [number](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron) [of](https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos) [packages](https://github.com/chrisspen/django-chroniker) that help do this, but they do not seem to support the latest Django version (4.0). Instead of continuing to search for packages, I was wondering if it is possible for me to simply write a python script within my Django folder structure, and manually configure a cron job to run this. Something like setting up:

```
*/30 * * * * python3.8 /var/djangoproject/crons/cron.py
```

Is this possible? Is there any drawback or risk in doing it like this instead of using a package that is made for this? I don't see anyone recommending this so before implementing it I wanted to see if this is a good idea.

Comment: Cron Jobs are very common, I use them in production for many tasks. I believe django-cron still needs a crontab configured anyways so just skip the middle man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is quite easy, and can be achieved by using [custom django-admin commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/). You basically add a `management/commands` folder to the project, and add a python script to that folder with a specific structure (see documentation). Say you call the file `cron.py`. Then a cron can be configured as such:

```
*/30 * * * * python3.8 /var/djangoproject/manage.py cron
```